# Mysql connection.query returning a value in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ubuntu

The flow of program must be like,

1. Run a query to get a list of names in the table.
2. Run a subquery for each name, to retrieve the names of folders each name uses
3. Search each folder to retrieve the total size of numerous files inside the folder.
4. Output like, name - number of folders - total size.

Asynchronous programming style is my problem.

As far the data that I collected from internet, I must use `connection.query` from `mysql` package, `fs.readdir` and `fs.stat` from `fs` package to accomplish the above flow.

But I am not able to accomplish that by the way I program. Could someone please provide a pseudo code for the above flow?

Each and every function that I designed is not returning a value.

Thanks.

Comment: check if the user `root@127.0.0.1` has access to the db.
Try 
```mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
    mysql -u root -p -h localhost```


See mysql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) for more info.

Comment: Can you give any errors for any of the functions?  Also you'll have to either turn these into promises or callbacks to have them go in order.  As if you do it procedurally connection.query will still be running when the other functions run and don't do anything.

Comment: Its not the exact error. I am unable to put all things into one working program. I am unable to think asynchronously. I am a R programmer like synchronous fashion. But this confuses me a lot.